# BatchNormalization in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, batch-normalization

How do I update moving mean and moving variance in keras BatchNormalization?

I found this in tensorflow documentation, but I don't know where to put `train_op` or how to work it with keras models:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
        with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
            train_op = optimizer.minimize( loss )
```

No posts I found say what to do with train_op and whether you can use it in `model.compile`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Generally you do not need to do anything for BatchNormalization to work in Keras.

Comment: I'm just trying to use BatchNormalization. What confuses me is the discrepancy between Tensorflow and Keras, so I'm not certain if I really don't need to do anything else (besides ensuring to turn off BatchNormalization during validation), or if I have to manually update the moving mean and variance.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro From the `optimizer.minimize(loss)`, it looks like he is trying to perform gradient descent steps manually (instead of using a higher-level API to drive the fitting). `optimizer.minimize()` (e.g. with 'AdamOptimizer' or 'GradientDescentOptimizer') will use gradient descent to update the regular weights for one step but it won't do anything to the batch norm mean & variance.

Comment: For me, `update_ops` is empty if I use `batch_normed = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(hidden, training=True)`. So no update of moving averages (e.g. `batch_normalization/moving_mean`) seem to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to manually update the moving mean and variances if you are using the BatchNormalization layer. Keras takes care of updating these parameters during training, and to keep them fixed during testing (by using the `model.predict` and `model.evaluate` functions, same as with `model.fit_generator` and friends).

Keras also keeps track of the learning phase so different codepaths run during training and validation/testing.

Comment: What if you are using model.fit_generator with training and validation sets?

Comment: @A.Hendry Same, I just forgot to mention it.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I doubt that works. I print out the first two elements of the the variable `batch_normalization/moving_mean` in my training loop that also uses `optimizer.minimize(loss)` and they never change. I'm using a `tensorflow.train.AdamOptimizer` and manually running `optimizer.minimize(loss)` to backpropagate weights updates. I suspect a higher-level API (e.g. `tensorflow.keras.models.Model.fit()`) is doing something to update the batch norm stats in addition to backpropagation, and that 'something' is missing from merely using `optimizer.minimize(loss)`.

Comment: @Syncopated I don't know what you are talking about, my answer is about using Keras, seems you aren't using pure Keras.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Seeing the question is tagged with with 'tensorflow' and 'keras', I'm talking about using keras in tensorflow, but seeing that the author seems to have accepted the answer, maybe he's not really talking about tensorflow.

Comment: @Syncopated The author was asking if you need to do tensorflow-style updates of the BN parameters if using Keras, and I just point out that it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just update the weights for existing model with some new values then you can do the following:

```
w = model.get_layer('batchnorm_layer_name').get_weights()
# Order: [gamma, beta, mean, std]
for j in range(len(w[0])):
    gamma = w[0][j]
    beta = w[1][j]
    run_mean = w[2][j]
    run_std = w[3][j]
    w[2][j] = new_run_mean_value1
    w[3][j] = new_run_std_value2

model.get_layer('batchnorm_layer_name').set_weights(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two interpretations of the question: the first is assuming that the goal is to use high level training api and this question was answered by Matias Valdenegro.

The second - as discussed in the comments - is whether it is possible to use batch normalization with the standard tensorflow optimizer as discussed here [keras a simplified tensorflow interface](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html) and the section "Collecting trainable weights and state updates". As mentioned there the update ops are accessible in layer.updates and not in `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`, in fact if you have a keras model in tensorflow you can optimize with a standard tensorflow optimizer and batch normalization like this

```
update_ops  = model.updates
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
     train_op = optimizer.minimize( loss )
```

and then use a tensorflow session to fetch the train_op. To distinguish training and evaluation modes of the batch normalization layer you need to feed the 
learning phase state of the keras engine (see "Different behaviors during training and testing" on the same [tutorial page](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html) as given above). This would work for example like this

```
... 
# train
lo, _ = tf_sess.run(fetches=[loss, train_step],
                    feed_dict={tf_batch_data: bd,
                               tf_batch_labels: bl,
                               tensorflow.keras.backend.learning_phase(): 1})

...

# eval
lo = tf_sess.run(fetches=[loss],
                    feed_dict={tf_batch_data: bd,
                               tf_batch_labels: bl,
                               tensorflow.keras.backend.learning_phase(): 0})
```

I tried this in tensorflow 1.12 and it works with models containing batch normalization. Given my existing tensorflow code and in the light of approaching tensorflow version 2.0 I was tempted to use this approach myself, but given that this approach is not being mentioned in the tensorflow documentation I am not sure this will be supported in the long term and I finally have decided to not use it and to invest a little bit more to change the code to use the high level api.