# Batch Normalization in tf.keras does not calculate average mean and average variance

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, batch-normalization

A similar unanswered question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164572/batchnormalization-in-keras).
I am testing one deep reinforcement learning algorithm which uses keras backend in tensorflow. I am not very familiar with tf.keras, nevertheless would like to add batch normalization layers. Therefore, I am trying to use `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()`, but it does not update average means and variances because `update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)` is empty.

Using the regular `tf.layers.batch_normalization` seem to work fine. However, because the complete algorithm is somewhat complicated, **I need to find a way to use `tf.keras`**.

A standard `tf` layer `batch_normed = tf.layers.batch_normalization(hidden, training=True)` updates the averages since `update_ops` is not empty:

```
[
    <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization/AssignMovingAvg' type=AssignSub>, 
    <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization/AssignMovingAvg_1' type=AssignSub>, 
    <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization_1/AssignMovingAvg' type=AssignSub>, 
    <tf.Operation 'batch_normalization_1/AssignMovingAvg_1' type=AssignSub>
]
```

Minimal example that does **not** work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.reset_default_graph()
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(True)

input_shapes = [(3, )]
hidden_layer_sizes = [16, 16]

inputs = [
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    for input_shape in input_shapes
]

concatenated = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda x: tf.concat(x, axis=-1)
)(inputs)

out = concatenated
for units in hidden_layer_sizes:      
    hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    units, activation=None
    )(out)
    batch_normed = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(hidden, training=True)
    #batch_normed = tf.layers.batch_normalization(hidden, training=True)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(batch_normed)

out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
    units=1, activation='linear'
)(out)


data = np.random.rand(100,3)
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(10):

    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)

    sess.run(update_ops,  {inputs[0]: data})
    sess.run(out, {inputs[0]: data})

    variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES,
                          scope='batch_normalization')
    bn_gamma, bn_beta, bn_moving_mean, bn_moving_variance = [], [], [], []
    for variable in variables:
        val = sess.run(variable)
        nv = np.linalg.norm(val)
        if 'gamma' in variable.name:
            bn_gamma.append(nv)
        if 'beta' in variable.name:
            bn_beta.append(nv)
        if 'moving_mean' in variable.name:
            bn_moving_mean.append(nv)
        if 'moving_variance' in variable.name:
            bn_moving_variance.append(nv)

        diagnostics = {
            'bn_Q_gamma': np.mean(bn_gamma),
            'bn_Q_beta': np.mean(bn_beta),
            'bn_Q_moving_mean': np.mean(bn_moving_mean),
            'bn_Q_moving_variance': np.mean(bn_moving_variance),
        }

    print(diagnostics)
```

The output is the following (you can see moving_mean and moving_variance not changing):

```
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 4.0}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 4.0}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 4.0}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 4.0}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 4.0}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 4.0}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 4.0}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 4.0}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 4.0}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 4.0}
```

While the expected output is something like the following (comment the line with `batch_normed` calculus using `tf.keras` and uncomment the one below it):

```
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.0148749575, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 3.966927}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.029601166, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 3.934192}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.04418011, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 3.9017918}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.05861327, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 3.8697228}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.0729021, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 3.8379822}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.08704803, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 3.8065662}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.10105251, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 3.7754717}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.11491694, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 3.7446957}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.12864274, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 3.7142346}
{'bn_Q_gamma': 4.0, 'bn_Q_beta': 0.0, 'bn_Q_moving_mean': 0.14223127, 'bn_Q_moving_variance': 3.6840856}
```

### Note

There is still something fishy even with `tf.layers.batch_normalization`. The standard `tf` approach of `tf.control_dependencies`:

```
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        sess.run(out, {inputs[0]: data})
```

which I place instead of the following two lines in the code above:

```
    sess.run(update_ops,  {inputs[0]: data})
    sess.run(out, {inputs[0]: data})
```

produces `bn_Q_moving_mean = 0.0` and `bn_Q_moving_variance = 4.0`

Comment: So how is that question is unanswered?

Comment: @Sharky Because Matias Valdenegro gave an answer which is about pure Keras, but not about the Tensorflow+Keras, see comments to his answer. Given Syncopated and my experience, tf.keras does not update moving averages automatically. Therefore, the question is still there: how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization` inherits from `tf.keras.layers.Layer`. Keras API handle update ops as part of its fit and evaluate loops. This in turn means that it won't update `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` collection without it.

So in order to make it work, you need to update it manually

```py
hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=None)(out)
batch_normed = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(trainable=True) 
layer = batch_normed(hidden)
```

This creates separate class instance

```py
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, batch_normed.updates)
```

And this updates needed collection. Also take a look https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25525

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot! Running `sess.run(update_ops,  {inputs[0]: data})` and then `sess.run(out, {inputs[0]: data})` worked fine for me. Do you know why `with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops): sess.run(out, {inputs[0]: data})` is still not working?

Comment: Updated answer, to the best of my khowledge(and as stated in the github link) keras simply doesn't have functionality to update collection within layer object, so it should be updated explicitly. Estimator and low level session can do it

Answer (score 2):

```
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, bn1.updates[0])
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, bn1.updates[1])
updates_op = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
```

this can solve

```
tf.control_dependencies(update_ops)
```

error problem.

if use

```
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, batch_normed.updates)
```

the return of

```
tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
```

is a list in list just like [[something]]

and use

```
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, bn1.updates[0])
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, bn1.updates[1])
updates_op = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
```

the return of

```
tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
```

is [something1,something2,...]

i thinks this is the solution.

but the out put is different,and i don't know which is true.